# Less 2.5 modifyVars() seems not work with Harp.js v0.15.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, pug, harp

I'm writing a Bootstrap 3 theme using Harp.js / jade / less

When I try to dynamically change the background color using less.modifyVar() function, the stylesheet is correctly reloaded but nothing happens ...

Less code (variables.less) :

```
@green            :       #59B75F;
@blue             :       #0081C5;
@base-color       :       @green;
```

Less code (custom.less) :

```
@import "variables.less";
.some_class {
    background-color: @base-color;
}
```

Jade code :

```
link(href="css/custom.css", rel="stylesheet/less", type="text/css")
script(src="bower_components/less/dist/less.min.js")
....
a(href="#", onclick="javascript:switchColor('#0081C5');") Blue
....
```

Javascript switchColor() function :

```
var switchColor = function(color) {
    less.modifyVars({'@base-color':color}); 
    less.refreshStyles();
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. C.

Comment: I think that in `link(href="css/custom.css", rel="stylesheet/less", type="text/css")` the `custom.css` file should have the `.less` extension ?

Comment: Hi Bass, harp server doesn't detect the file if the extension is `.less`. http://harpjs.com/docs/development/less

Comment: well see, http://harpjs.com/docs/development/less under "usage": Just name your file with an .less extension instead of .css and the Harp web server will see it as if it is a .css file. But when you load less.js and a .less according to compile has nothing to do with the harp server in de first place. See: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

Comment: @ceadreak actually has the right approach here. Name the LESS file `custom.less` and it’s automatically served to the browser as `custom.css`—so you still need to reference it as `custom.css` in the HTML.

Comment: So as is it turned out, your less files are compiled server-side, thus you *don't* need to include the client-side `less.js` script in you page, but obviously this also means that you *can't* change any variables "dynamically" since your CSS is pre-compiled and there's no Less code the client-side `less.modifyVars` can change.

Answer (score -1):

sorry for any confusion. Harp v0.15.2 is the latest version, and is still running LESS v1.x. We have just been working on updating to LESS 2.5.0 this weekend and [it landed in Terraform](https://github.com/sintaxi/terraform), Harp’s preprocessing engine.

<del>A new release of Harp will be out very soon that will include that update. (We’ll post it [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/harpwebserver) if you’d like a notification.)</del>

**Edit** Harp v0.17.0 is now the latest version, upgrading should fix this problem:

```
npm install --global harp
```